# SQLAlchemy Join a table with a view

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following table

```
class WeeknumTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'WeeknumTable'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'ww'}

    dt = Column(TIMESTAMP(), primary_key=True)
    weeknum = Column(String(10), index=True)
    fy = Column(Numeric(10, 0))
```

And the following view

```
v_someview = Table(

    'someview', metadata,

    Column('dt', TIMESTAMP()),
    Column('wk_begin', TIMESTAMP(),ForeignKey("WeeknumTable.dt")),
    Column('iwp', Float(53)),

    schema='ww',
    week_begin = relationship(WeeknumTable)
```

)

trying to import this in jupyter fails with: Can't validate argument 'week_begin'; can't locate any SQLAlchemy dialect named 'week'
  (k, dialect_name))

Any hints how to join the view and the table properly so that I can use the table's fields in my filters?